# SQLHow do I modify this query to select unique by hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

(Looking for a better title)

Hello I have the query below

```
Declare @CDT varchar(23)
Declare @CDT2 varchar(23)
set @cdt = '2016-01-18 00:00:00.000'
set @cdt2 = '2016-01-26 00:00:00.000'
SELECT
    spt.number AS [Hour of Day],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM history t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.calldatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectid IN (5) and calldatetime between @cdt and @cdt2) AS [Project  5  ],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM history t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.calldatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectid IN (124) and calldatetime between @cdt and @cdt2) AS [Project  124],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM history t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.calldatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectid IN (576) and calldatetime between @cdt and @cdt2) AS [Project  576]
FROM master..spt_values spt
WHERE spt.number BETWEEN 0 AND 11 AND spt.type = 'p'
GROUP BY spt.number
ORDER BY spt.number
```

I now need to select a unique number per hour rather than a distinct ammount overall.

for instance if I run this with the "select distinct(Agentid), rest of query here, it will give me a count of agentids, independant of the cases, how do I "WHEN AGENTID is unique"?

I copied examples from the original question

```
Project id  Datetime                 Agentid
----------  -----------------------  ---------
5           11-23-2015 09:00:00.000  12
5           11-23-2015 10:00:00.000  12
6           11-23-2015 11:00:00.000  12
1           11-23-2015 12:00:00.000  3
3           11-23-2015 13:00:00.000  4
124         11-23-2015 14:00:00.000  7
124         11-23-2015 15:00:00.000  9
124         11-23-2015 16:00:00.000  10
576         11-23-2015 17:00:00.000  10
576         11-23-2015 18:00:00.000  44
576         11-23-2015 19:00:00.000  69
etc         11-23-2015 20:00:00.000  23
```

Expected output (Ignore the incorrect counts, assume they are correct from above^):

```
Datetime       5    124  576
-------------  ---  ---  ---
09:00 - 09:59  0    4    5
10:00 - 10:59  4    3    1
11:00 - 11:59  5    2    1
12:00 - 12:59  1    1    1
13:00 - 13:59  6    1    1
14:00 - 14:59  6    1    1
15:00 - 15:59  7    1    2
16:00 - 16:59  8    1    3
17:00 - 17:59  9    1    3
18:00 - 18:59  1    1    2
19:00 - 19:59  12   1    0
20:00 - 20:59  0    0    0
```

so far

```
Hour of Day Project  5      Project  124    Project  576
0                    0                 0    0
1                    0                 0              0
2                    0                 0              0
3                    0                 0              0
4                    0                 0              0
5                    0                 0              0
6                    0                 0              0
7                    0                 0              0
8                    0                 0              0
9                    0                 0              0
10                   0                 0              0
11                   0                 0              0
```

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table conditions in the ON clause to get true left join result. (When in WHERE clause, it executes as a regular inner join.)

Comment: @jarlh elaborate please?

Comment: Okay Tab, Changing it now

Comment: @ConradFrix perhaps the update I made, made these clearer

Comment: Hello Tab Allerman, essentially I am looking for a modification that would only select the number of unique agentids per "hour" so imagine 300 records within one of the hours, that would be great but now I need to know how many agents were active in that hour.

Comment: Were you getting results before you added the Date filters to the sub-queries?   Maybe you don't have any data in that date range?

Comment: @TabAlleman We'll pick this up when I come back in 16-17 hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101754/discussion-between-dansmith-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to do this with subqueries:

```
SELECT
    spt.number AS [Hour of Day],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM YourTable t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.yourdatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectId IN (5)) AS [Project  5  ],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM YourTable t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.yourdatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectId IN (124)) AS [Project  124],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId) 
     FROM YourTable t2
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, t2.yourdatetime)=spt.number
     AND projectId IN (576)) AS [Project  576]
FROM master..spt_values spt
WHERE spt.number BETWEEN 0 AND 11 AND spt.type = 'p'
GROUP BY spt.number
ORDER BY spt.number
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "master..spt_values.number" could not be bound.
Any idea?

Comment: Notice that I have aliased the table, so if you have done the same, you need to use the alias instead of the table name everywhere you reference it in the query.   Which I see I missed in the first column, and will fix now.

Comment: now the last part, how do I tell it a specific date, normally I'd use and yourdatetime between '11-23-2015 00:00:00.000' and '11-24-2015 00:00:00.000' but that errors.

Comment: You will need to put that condition (`and yourdatetime between '11-23-2015 00:00:00.000' and '11-24-2015 00:00:00.000'`) in each of the sub-query's `where` clauses.

Comment: okay, i'm close I got hours of day and a near complete query, but now all I am pulling is blanks.

Comment: Edit your post and add your version of the query that is returning blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the table used by these queries:

```
DECLARE @wt TABLE (
projectid varchar(4) not null,
edate datetime not null,
agentid int not null );
```

If you want to get the counts by time and project, use this query:

```
SELECT edate, projectid, COUNT(*) as nentries
FROM @wt
GROUP BY edate, projectid;
```

I haven't dealt with bucketing the dates by hour; that is a separate issue.
To get a tabular result set as you have shown:

```
SELECT edate, [5] AS [Project 5], [124] AS [Project 124], [576] AS [Project 576]
FROM (
    SELECT edate, CAST(projectid AS int) AS projectid
        FROM @wt
        WHERE ISNUMERIC(projectid) <> 0 ) AS s
PIVOT (
    COUNT(projectid)
    FOR projectid IN ([5], [124], [576])) AS p;
```

Here is the result set for the PIVOT query using the above data:
[image: PIVOT result set]

However, you have to specify the projects of interest in the query. If you want to have an arbitrary number of projects and get columns for each one, that is going to require dynamic SQL to construct the PIVOT query.

@Tab Alleman: I added some data to illustrate the conditions that will test your scenario. Here is the result set with the same PIVOT query:

[image: Enhanced result set]

Comment: But can this approach be modified to count DISTINCT AgentIds in each Project/Hour bucket?   Read the OP's last comment as of this writing.  The one that starts "Hello Tab Allerman...").

Comment: See most recent edit to answer. The query accomplishes this without modification.

Comment: How does it count distinct AgentIds without even mentioning AgentId anywhere in the query?

Comment: For edate = 18:00, the `s` subquery is going to give two rows with `projectid` = 576. The PIVOT rollup counts those rows. If it were possible for the same `agentid` to be on the same `projectid` for the same `edate` multiple times, there would be more complexity to recognize and address that condition.

Comment: That's what OP's last comment is saying, it is possible for the same AgentId to be on the same ProjectId multiple times within the same hour, and he needs to count each unique AgentId only once within each Project/Hour bucket.

Comment: this also ignores mytable completely and creates its own :S

Comment: Substitute your table and column names for the names in the query.

Comment: @TabAlleman: when bucketing by hour, also select distinct agent IDs.